# C Programming: Forward variable argument list

Tags: c, variables, arguments, printf, forward

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a variable number of parameters like printf, does some stuff, then passes the variable list to printf. I'm not sure how to do this, because it seems like it would have to push them onto the stack.

Something approximately like this

http://pastie.org/694844

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void forward_args( const char *format , ... ){
  va_list arglist;
  printf( format, arglist );
}


int main (int argc, char const *argv[]){
  forward_args( "%s %s\n" , "hello" , "world" );  return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you and John are in the same class?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714550/how-can-one-variable-args-function-call-another

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forward an invocation of a variadic function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Don't pass the results to `printf`. pass them to `vprintf`.  `vprintf` specifically exists to handle passing in `va_list` arguments.  From the Linux man page:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printf(const char *format, ...);
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);

#include <stdarg.h>

int vprintf(const char *format, va_list ap);
int vfprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, va_list ap);
int vsprintf(char *str, const char *format, va_list ap);
int vsnprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, va_list ap);
```

Notice how the latter explicitly take `va_list` arguments such as the ones you declare inside a function taking `...` in the parameter list.  So your function would be declared like this:

```
void forward_args( const char *format , ... ){
   va_list arglist;
   va_start( arglist, format );
   vprintf( format, arglist );
   va_end( arglist );
}
```

Comment: Well, he needs to `va_start()` and `va_end()` also.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Oof.  I thought I fixed that.  Moral: Don't write code tired, even code you are just cutting and pasting.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Hi, Ken, I saw your name and had to think for about 15 minutes to figure out where I recognized it from... I've seen you on the Ruby mailing list ^_^ Thanks for the help, both Ken and quark.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for `va_start()` / `vprintf()` / `vsnprintf()` / `va_end()`, there's no need to implement these yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be passing along the arglist value to a function designed to consume it.  See the stdarg and vprintf documentation for more clues.