# Is it possible to write a varargs function that sends it argument list to another varargs function?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Programming: Forward variable argument list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719784/c-programming-forward-variable-argument-list)

What I'd like to do is send data to a logging library (that I can't modfify) in a printf kind of way.

So I'd like a function something like this:

```
void log_DEBUG(const char* fmt, ...) {
   char buff[SOME_PROPER_LENGTH];
   sprintf(buff, fmt, <varargs>);
   log(DEBUG, buff);
}
```

Can I pass varargs to another vararg function in some manner?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719784/c-programming-forward-variable-argument-list

Comment: I believe this is not a duplicate, as 1719784 is about C and this question is about C++ where that kind of construct is doable using variadic template functions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't forward the variable argument list, since there's no way to express what's underneath the `...` as a parameter(s) to another function.

However you can build a `va_list` from the `...` parameters and send *that* to a function which will format it up properly.  This is what [`vsprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) is for.  Example:

```
void log_DEBUG(const char* fmt, ...) {
   char buff[SOME_PROPER_LENGTH];
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, fmt);
   vsprintf(buff, fmt, args);
   va_end(args);
   log(DEBUG, buff);
}
```

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: I don't see anything non-standard here.

Comment: I thought that va_list was itself non-standard.  Could be wrong.

Comment: Nope. The only thing in `stdarg.h` (or `cstdarg`) not part of C89 (and therefore C++) is `va_copy` which was added in C99.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Or at least, not as it was presented in the sample code... mysprintf is not sprintf and the arguments are not forwarded.  The other answers referencing vprintf I think are better.

Comment: @Jason: The other answers were better in the sense that they used `vsprintf` instead of some hand-rolled monstrosity.  I've improved my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

You can send it to another function that takes a va_list as an argument. There is no other way, short of resorting to hand crafted asm, or doing some kind of horrifying guessing game to figure out the 'number' of parameters.

This would work:

```
void log_DEBUG(const char* fmt, ...)
{
  va_list va;
  va_start(va,fmt);
  char buff[blah];
  vsprintf(buff,fmt,va);
  log(DEBUG,buff);
  va_end(va);
}
```

Basically, whenever you write a function that takes ..., you should write another version that takes a va_list - its the polite thing to do if you want to enable this type of chaining call.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  I was thinking maybe there was someway to pass the arg list directly, but vsprintf will do nicely!

Comment: the accepted answer missed the "vsprintf" point which is why many folks (inc me) will google this answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is why you have the [`vprintf`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/vprintf/) family of functions.

Answer (score 4):

For your specific requirement, you can use [`vsprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vsprintf/). My C/C++ is too rusty to recall if there's a straightforward way to do it when the other function isn't designed for it (without getting into ugly stack manipulation), but I tend to think not.

Answer (score 3):

Not in standard C++.

Comment: Right, in C++ it would be preferable to use `<<`

Comment: Not in standard C, but starting with C++11 a very similar behavior can be done using variadic template functions.