# forward argslist "..." from a c++ to c function

Tags: c++, c, arguments, wrapper

forward argument list from a c++ class member function to a c function, (a wrapper I am creating)

not sure if it is correct? look in the comment inside argsPrinter

```
// c++ a class function

void argsPrinter( const char *format , ... ){
   //markFile(&mApiObj, format , ...); how to pass forward the ... to the c function

/*
va_list args;
va_start (args, format);
markFile(&mApiObj, format , args);
va_end(args);
*/
}

// c function

void markFile(someCustomApi* a, const char *format , ...)
{
   FILE *file= fopen(a->somePath, "a");
   if(file)
   {
     va_list args;
     va_start (args, format);
     vfprintf(file, format, args);
     va_end (args);
     fclose(file);
   }
//else do nothing
}
```

**Edit**
the implementation changed, however, I may consider implementing an aditional function, if forward is not allowed to the ...

as `markFile(&mApiObj, format , ...);`

Comment: [This][1] may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719784/c-programming-forward-variable-argument-list
Please try more search, before you post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one variable-args function call another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714550/how-can-one-variable-args-function-call-another)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++: Passing variable number of arguments around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. If the library containing `markFile` doesn't provide a `markFileV` (similar to `vsprintf` being the counterpart to `sprintf`), it's just not possible to do this.

Given that you have the source of the C function, you may be able to change that, though.

On a side note (if you have any influence on the C code), this may be a reduced example, but why is `markFile` first formatting into a buffer (that is `PATH_MAX` chars long, of all things! What does that have to do with anything?) and then using `fprintf` to write out the results? Why not just use `vfprintf` directly?

Comment: I can change that, I had written this function long time ago, wasnt sure of the existence of vfprintf,

Comment: I made the change, and considering to add a new function to the c file.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to forward C-style variadic arguments. That's why both `fprintf` and `vfprintf` exist. If you need to forward them, you'll have to create your own version of `markFile`, something like `vmarkFile`, which would accept a `va_list` instead of `...`.

Answer (score 1):

How about just call your C++ function inside implementation of C function?

Such as your C++ function

```
void argsPrinter( const char *format , ... ){
   //markFile(&mApiObj, format , ...); how to pass forward the ... to the c function

   /*
   va_list args;
   va_start (args, format);
   markFile(&mApiObj, format , args);
   va_end(args);
   */
}
```

You can implement your C function by calling it:

```
void markFile(someCustomApi* a, const char *format , ...)
{
   a->argsPrinter(format, ... );
   //else do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is highly ABI dependent you can not do this easily.

Alternatively you can use [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/). Look for variadic function call in the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/info/libffi/libffi-3.0.11/libffi.php#Top).

I still recommend that you write a function that accept a `va_list`  as parameter like `vsprintf` and co.