# passing variable number of arguments

Tags: c, function, variadic-functions, variadic

Can we pass variable number of arguments to a function in c?

Comment: Such a function is called a [variadic function](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html) (for those seeking good search keywords).

Comment: Haven't you ever used `printf`?

Comment: I have used it but didnt know much about using variadic functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html) is an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int maxof(int, ...) ;
void f(void);

int main(void){
        f();
        exit(EXIT SUCCESS);
}

int maxof(int n_args, ...){
        register int i;
        int max, a;
        va_list ap;

        va_start(ap, n_args);
        max = va_arg(ap, int);
        for(i = 2; i <= n_args; i++) {
                if((a = va_arg(ap, int)) > max)
                        max = a;
        }

        va_end(ap);
        return max;
}

void f(void) {
        int i = 5;
        int j[256];
        j[42] = 24;
        printf("%d\n", maxof(3, i, j[42], 0));
}
```

Comment: I don't get the use of the `register` here?

Comment: The use of `register` is evidence that the code sample is quite old.  Use of `register` is a hint to the compiler to place the variable into a machine register, as a performance optimisation.  The majority of C compilers over the last 30 years have ignored that hint, since they can do a better job of register allocation than most programmers can.   Nowadays, `register` has few effects other than forbidding calculation of the address of a variable.

Answer (score 6):

If it is [a function that accepts a variable number of arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D), yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the function accepts variable arguments. If you need to make your own variable-argument function, there are macros that begin with va_ which give you access to the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the variable argument list should always be at the end of the argument list

example: `void func(float a, int b, ...)` is correct

but `void func(float a, ..., int b)` is not valid

Comment: Yes, but this is more of a comment than an answer.  Certainly, you've explained one aspect, but it is a very minor aspect of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"You should consider that using variadic functions (C-style) **is a dangerous flaw**," says Stephane Rolland. You can find his helpful post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555583/passing-variable-number-of-arguments-with-different-type-c/).

Comment: I believe the advice is for writing your own custom variadic functions in C++ and not for the ones provided by the standard library. Just, imagine life without `printf`!