# Function with unknown number of parameters in C

Tags: c, function, variadic-functions

How can I write (if it's possible at all...) a function which takes an unknown number of parameters in C99 (the return type is constant)?

Comment: You mean a variadic function? Like `printf`? Have you looked up `<varargs.h>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing variable number of arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836272/passing-variable-number-of-arguments)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes you can do it in C using what are referred to as Variadic Functions. 
The standard [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) and [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) functions do this, for example.

Put the ellipsis (three dots) as the last parameter where you want the 'variable number of parameters to be.

To access the parameters include the `<stdarg.h>` header:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

And then you have a special type `va_list` which gives you the list of arguments passed, and you can use the `va_start`, `va_arg` and `va_end` macros to iterate through the list of arguments.

For example:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

int myfunc(int count, ...)
{
   va_list list;
   int j = 0;

   va_start(list, count); 
   for(j=0; j<count; j++)
   {
     printf("%d", va_arg(list, int));
   }

   va_end(list);

   return count;
}
```

Example call:

```
myfunc(4, -9, 12, 43, 217);
```

A full example can be found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D).

The `count` parameter in the example tells the called function how many arguments are passed. The `printf()` and `scanf()` find that out via the format string, but a simple `count` argument can do it too. Sometimes, code uses a sentinel value, such as a negative integer or a null pointer (see 
[`execl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execl.html)
for example).

Comment: Kinda old question but I saw in a Cuda C example inside the main function something like `int N = ...;`  What does this mean?