# C : write a function doesn't know how many parameter

Tags: c, parameters, variadic-functions

When learning C I see that `printf` can receive many arguments as it is passed.

And I don't know how C can implement a function like this, where the user can type as many parameters as the user wants. I have thought about pointers, too but still have no bright idea. If anyone has any ideas about this type of function, please tell me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing variable number of arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836272/passing-variable-number-of-arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use va_args, va_list and the like.
Have a look at this tutorial.
    http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html

That should be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `...` notation in your function declaration as the last argument.

Please see this tutorial to learn more: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just pay careful heed to the warning about the lack of type checking with variable arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You use C `varargs` to write a *variadic function*. You'll need to include `stdargs.h`, which gives you macros for iterating over an argument list of unknown size: `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end`, using a datatype: `va_list`.

Here's a mostly useless function that prints out it's variable length argument list:

```
void printArgs(const char *arg1, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char *str;

    if (arg1) We

        va_start(args, arg1);

        printf("%s ", arg1);

        while ((str = va_arg(argp, char *)) != NULL)
            printf("%s ", str);

        va_end(args);
    }
}

...

printArgs("print", "any", "number", "of", "arguments");
```

[Here's](http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html) a more interesting example that demonstrates that you can iterate over the argument list more than once.

Note that there are type safety issues using this feature; the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stdarg.h#Type_safety) addresses some of this.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int add_all(int num,...)
{
    va_list args;
    int sum = 0;
    va_start(args,num);
    int x = 0;
    for(x = 0; x < num;x++)
        sum += va_arg(args,int);
    va_end(args);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Added 2 + 5 + 3: %d\n",add_all(3,2,5,3));
}
```