# How to use __VA_ARGS__ inside a C function instead of macro?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Passing variable number of arguments around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around)

I'm currently using the following macro declared on my C file.

```
#define COMMON_Print(...) printf (__VA_ARGS__)
```

Now that call works just fine, but turns out that I need to be able to create a C function that looks something like this:

```
void COMMON_Print(...)
{    
    printf (__VA_ARGS__);
}
```

So that function doesn't work, I get an error

> "Error   : undefined identifier __VA_ARGS__"

The complexity of my project requires to have a function since it's an interface... So how can I get the parameters ... and pass them to the printf function? Or better what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Each of the `?printf` functions has a corresponding `v?printf` function which does the same thing but takes a `va_list`, a variable argument list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void COMMON_Print(char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

**Side note:** Notice that `va_start` takes the name of the last argument before the `...` as a parameter. `va_start` is a macro which does some stack-based magic to retrieve the variable arguments and it needs the address of the last fixed argument to do this.

As a consequence of this, there has to be at least one fixed argument so you can pass it to `va_start`. This is why I added the `format` argument instead of sticking with the simpler `COMMON_Print(...)` declaration.

**See:** http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vprintf/

Comment: If you use macros, you need no preceding arg. Consider this example: `#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))` This obviously is very convenient from a usage viewpoint.

Answer (score 24):

`__VA_ARGS__` is only for macros; variadic functions are rather different. You need to use [`va_start`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/), `va_arg` and `va_end` from `stdarg.h` to handle them.

First, your function needs at least one named parameter, e.g.:

```
void COMMON_Print(const char* fmt, ...)
```

Then you can define a `va_list` and use `va_start` to set it:

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, fmt);
// your code here
va_end(args);
```

Now you can use `args` to access the arguments; calling `va_arg(args, TYPE)` will return the next variadic argument, so you can just keep calling that until you've read all the arguments.

If you're just trying to call `printf`, there's a printf variant called `vprintf` that takes the `va_list` directly:

```
vprintf(fmt, args);
```

There is no easy way to call one variadic function from another; you need something like `vprintf` that takes the whole `va_list`

Comment: 'va_arg(args, TYPE)' will return NULL only if NULL was passed by the caller. There is no default end condition for va_arg. You must either pass a sentinel value or know the exact number of parameters, passed by a parameter or by counting the number of % in a printf format string.

Comment: @tristopia Oh, right; I'm in the habit of passing NULL at the end when necessary. Fixed

Answer (score 8):

`__VA_ARGS__` is for macros only.

Chaining the variable number of argument to another function can't be done directly. Instead you have to
pass a va_list , and the function you're calling have to take a va_list. Luckily there's a variation of printf that does this, your function have to be written this way:

```
void COMMON_Print(char *format,...)
{    
  va_list args;
  va_start(args,format);
  vprintf(format,args);
  va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!  It actually works! But there are some formatting issues going on that I need to resolve on my end I believe.  FYI, I'm working on an embedded device.

Comment: What is vaprintf ? Or is it just a typo ?

Comment: There are two errors in this code sample. The first call should be to `va_start` and not `va_begin` and the second call to `vprintf` not `vsprintf`.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the [Ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28programming_operator%29#C_and_C.2B.2B) operator.