# C++ variadic constructor - pass to parent constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, overriding

I have th following code:

```
class A{

    //Constructor
    public: A(int count,...){
        va_list vl;
        va_start(vl,count);
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            /*Do Something ... */
        va_end(vl);
    }
};

class B : public A{

    //Constructor should pass on args to parent
    public: B(int count,...) : A(int count, ????)
    {}
};
```

How can I do that?

Note: I would prefer to have call the constructor in the initialization list and not in the constructor body. But if this is the only way, I am also interested to hear how this works!

Thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using?  You want [the new C++0x initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists).

Comment: He wants a non-sucky initializer, if you ask me- ahem. More importantly, he wants constructor forwarding or variadic template.s

Comment: Several duplicates, one of them:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around

Comment: @Kiril: It's no duplicate. I can't use va_list in the initialization inline list. Why wasting everybodies time (including yours) with such comments?

Comment: @Ben: I dont want C++0x. I want the old standard's initialization list.

Comment: @user578832: I said "initializer list" and I meant *initializer list*.  They're a new feature of C++0x, different from the *ctor-initializer* which I think is what you are referring to as an "initialization list".  Nothing in this question gave any clue to the fact that you can't use C++0x, so I suggested the best solution assuming you could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot forward on to an ellipsis. The second constructor will have to take a `va_list`, I think it is.

This *would* be possible with C++0x's base constructor forwarding, or variadic templates.

Comment: Those are great when the base class has a fixed number of parameters, unknown to you.  Variadic arguments are something else, and are handled (and easily forwarded) by `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Actually, if the parameters aren't all the same type, you would need a variadic template, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Ben: Yea. You can inherit base constructors though, which really settles the whole thing. `struct b { b(/* anything */); } struct d : b { using b::b; }; // le done`

Comment: Except that, at least for g++, base constructors with C-style variadic arguments are simply dropped: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-10/msg02294.html