# Initializing an object using constructor with variable number of parametes in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I want to write a code in c++ so that the I can initialize a class using a constructor with unknown number of parameters. I have an array in my class and i want to store all the values that i pass to my constructor to be stored in the array. Is it possible to do so.

Comment: Why not simply have an array (or vector) as a constructor parameter?

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?  This is possible in two ways with C++11.  Either variadic templates, or initializer lists.

Comment: For an array as the parameter, http://liveworkspace.org/code/7823999f46ff0a4fa45674f695b3f9ab. A vector or something would be better if you have C++11.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179812

Comment: I compile on ideone which uses C++ (gcc-4.3.4).

Comment: That's a bit odd.  If, for whatever reason, you are forced to use an online compiler, here's one that uses gcc 4.7, and it includes an up to date version of boost: http://liveworkspace.org/

Answer (score 2):

The best approach in C++11 would be to have a construcor that takes a `std::initializer_list<T>` where `T` is the type stored in the array.

Other options include taking a pointer to a different array, or a `std::vector<T>` (BTW, consider using `std::vector` rather than a plain array).