# Creating a proxy function to fprintf in an unobtrusive way?

Tags: c, exception, argument-passing

I'd like to create a proxy to `fprintf`, like so:

```
void raise_exception(char *filename, int line, char *format_string, ...) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Exception in `%s`:%d!\n", filename, line);
    fprintf(stderr, format_string, ...);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

But what do I put in the place of the second ellipsis? Is it *at all* possible?

I'd like to simplify it even a bit more like so:

```
#define RAISE(...) raise_exception(__FILE__, __LINE__, ...)
```

But I don't think this would work either.

Any ideas? Thanks!

### UPDATE

Straight from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro):

> Variable-argument macros were introduced in the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99)

So the define that would do it should look like so:

```
#define RAISE(...) raise_exception(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: I suggest making the macro: `#define RAISE(fmt, ...) raise_exception(__FILE__, __LINE__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)` so that people can't try to pass no arguments to RAISE.

Comment: I agree. That's definitely better style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <stdarg.h>
void raise_exception(char *filename, int line, char *format_string, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    fprintf(stderr, "Exception in `%s`:%d!\n", filename, line);
    va_start(args, format_string);
    vfprintf(stderr, format_string, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`vfprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vfprintf/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this question:

[Passing variable number of arguments around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around)

Your exact example -- of wrapping printf -- is used as an example in the discussion here:

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html