# How to create a function to call a variable arg function?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Passing variable number of arguments around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around)

I need to put all functions calling into a C API into a separate source file unit.  It is due to defines interfering with other code.  So to keep the possibly interfering code separate.

Anyway, most functions are eg int function2(int) so I just implement in separate file like this:

```
int XXfunction1(int val) { return function(val) }
```

But I also have functions with variable arguments like this:

```
extern int function2(int, ...)
```

So how can I write my own function which calls that?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
int XXFunction2(int val, ...) {
   return function2(val, ...);
}
```

How do I write the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a "v" version of your method that can take a variadic list.

```
int function2v(int val, va_list arg_list)
{
    //Work directly with the va_list
}

//And to call it
int XXFunction2(int val, ...) {
   int returnVal;
   va_list list;
   va_start(list, val);

   returnVal = function2v(val, list);

   va_end(list);

   return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Function2 must be declared before XXFunction2 for it to work. What you can do is to but the function signature on a .h file and import it before using, otherwise C can't find Function2 while compiling XXFunction2, leading to a compiling error.

Comment: This answer isn't relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Accurate as far as it goes, but missing the point of the question.