# How do I wrap around open?

Tags: c

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ... );
```

The problem is that its arguments aren't fixed,

is there a way to wrap around it?

```
int my_open(const char *path, int oflag, ... ){

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by wrap? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Etienne de Martel,so that calling `my_open` do the same thing as calling `open`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To wrap a variadic function in the general case, it needs to have a variant that takes the `va_list` as an argument (this is what the `vprintf` family of functions are for, for instance).

However, `open` only ever has two or three arguments, so it can be wrapped by conditionally reading the third argument, but *unconditionally* passing three arguments to the real `open`:

```
#ifndef O_TMPFILE
# define O_TMPFILE 0
#endif
int my_open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)
{
    mode_t mode = 0;
    if (flags & (O_CREAT|O_TMPFILE))
    {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, flags);
        mode = va_arg(ap, mode_t);
        va_end(ap);
    }
    // ... do what you need to do here ...
    return open(pathname, flags, mode);
}
```

This works because extra arguments to a variadic function are harmless; they'll just get ignored.  However, you will need to update the `if` condition every time the operating systems you care about add new flags that require the third parameter.  The original version of this answer didn't account for `O_TMPFILE`, for instance.  (It's *not* safe to read the third parameter unconditionally; if the compiler ever managed to notice that you were reading a parameter that wasn't passed, it would be nasal demons time.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no open() function defined in the C language standard. Although open() by POSIX

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

As Etienne asked - "What are you trying to do"

Answer (score 0):

Early versions of the `open()` function were described with an optional argument, but modern POSIX defines it as a variadic function with `, ...` in its prototype.

Wrapping a variadic function with another is generally difficult, which is why the standard has `vfprintf()` and friends.  But since the valid variations for `open()` are quite simple, with the presence or absence of the third argument determined by the value of the second, you can use a simpler approach.

Write your own `my_open()` function that uses `<stdarg.h>` to access the optional third argument.  Depending the value of `oflag`, do either

```
return open(path, oflag);
```

or

```
return open(path, oflag, third_arg);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't wrap open() without using inline assembly or SWIG (a library for calling C)

see 
http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: wow, holy downvotes folks.  As the OP's post has now been entirely rewritten to clarify what his question was, I suggest another SO post which has a good discussion: [Passing variable number of arguments around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around)

Comment: The problem is how you pass the rest of params to `open`?

Comment: Oh really - and explain to me how you pass the rest of the parameters without using vargs et al