# Calling function with variable number of arguments from a function with a variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Passing variable number of arguments around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around)

Imagine I have a function `mySuperDuperPrintFunction` that takes a variable number of arguments. This function calls `printf` (or any other function with a variable number of arguments. Can i somehow pass *all*, or only some, parameters from the *arglist* to the other function ? Like

```
void mySuperDuperPrintFunction(char* text, ...) {

    /*
     * Do some cool stuff with the arglist.
     */

    // Call printf with arguments from the arglist
    printf(text, *someWayToExtractTheArglist());
}
```

Comment: You should look at calling `vprintf` instead.

Comment: Is this C or C++? In C++ the answer is probably, "don't". In C, you would essentially be looking at some inverse of the `va_arg` unpacking magic. I'm not sure whether the standard provides one at all.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? The OP asks if and how one can *modify* the valist, which is not the same as just passing it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, text);

vprintf(format_goes_here, args);
```

You can find info about `vprintf` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vprintf/) (or check your man pages).

I've done similar for wrapping functions such as `write` (Unix) and [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows) so that I could create a formatted string to pass to them with `vsnprintf`.

**EDIT:** I misunderstood your question. No you can't, at least not in C. If you want to pass the variable number of arguments on, the function you're calling must take a `va_list` argument, just like `vprintf` does. You can't pass your `va_list` onto a function such as `printf(const char *fmt,`**`...`**`)`. [This link](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html) contains more information on the topic.

If the function *does* take a `va_list` argument, then you *can* pass arguments from a specific point (ie. you might to skip the first one). Retrieving arguments with `va_arg` will update the `va_list` pointer to the next argument, and then when you pass the `va_list` to the function (such as `vprintf`), it'll only be able to retrieve arguments from that point on.

Comment: "or any other function with a variable number of arguments" - `vprintf` is not the same, I need to call the function that does actually take the variable number of arguments. Thanks

Comment: @NiklasR oh, I was assuming you wanted a function like `vprintf`. I don't *think* it's possible (at least in C), unless the argument is `va_list`, like with `vprintf`.

Comment: @NiklasR updated my answer in regards to your question about "...or only some." It still only relates to using a `va_list` though.