# Variable number arguments in a c function

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Passing variable number of arguments around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around)

How can I do a function that has a variable number of arguments.
For example:

```
      typedef enum{
              Circle, /* has an int argument (int colour)*/
              Square /* has a char argument (char name)*/
      }things;

      /* if arg is a ball I want an int (with colour) argument in f*/
      /* if arg is a square I want a char (with name) argument in f*/
      void f (things arg, ...){
      }
```

Is this possible to do in the same function f? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around ?

Comment: @Zeta That question is about passing variable arguments to another function, not how to get variable arguments in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is a [example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html#Variadic-Example) of how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html) it is done, which finds the max of a variable number of numbers.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int maxof(int, ...) ;
void f(void);

main(){
        f();
        exit(EXIT SUCCESS);
}

int maxof(int n args, ...){
        register int i;
        int max, a;
        va_list ap;

        va_start(ap, n args);
        max = va_arg(ap, int);
        for(i = 2; i <= n_args; i++) {
                if((a = va_arg(ap, int)) > max)
                        max = a;
        }

        va_end(ap);
        return max;
}

void f(void) {
        int i = 5;
        int j[256];
        j[42] = 24;
        printf("%d\n",maxof(3, i, j[42], 0));
}
```