# What's the meaning of the `...` parameter in a C function parameter list

Tags: c, function-parameter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Passing variable number of arguments around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around)

According to the function declaration manner

`return-type function-name(parameter-list, ...) {body ...}`

Is the following code a kind of overloading?

(in A_FILE.h)

`typedef VOID *FUNCTION(UINTN  Number, ...);`

It seems that I could just pass one `Number` parameter, or more parameters into the `FUNCTION` function, so does the number of parameters depends on the function implementation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ellipsis within *a function declaration* means that it will accept a number of arguments  otherwise, variable parameters that are unknown at run-time, which by using the standard header file `stdarg.h`, the respective functions in that header file 'stdarg.h' can determine what each of the variable parameters are that makes up the argument passing into a function.

Consider this code example:

```
#define PANIC_BUF_LEN 256
void panic(const char *fmt, ...){
    char buf[PANIC_BUF_LEN];
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, fmt);
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    fprintf(stderr, buf);
    exit(errcode);
}
```

Typical invocation can be one of example:

```
panic("Error: %s failed! Due to unknown error, message is '%s'\n", "my_function", "Disk not ready");
```

Will produce an output on console in this manner:

```
Error: my_function failed! Due to unknown error, message is 'Disk not ready'
```

Notice the usage of how the functions `va_start(...)`, `va_end(...)` and not to mention `vsprintf(...)` will take care of filling in the blanks within the "unknown" parameters *provided* `va_list` is initialized to *point* to the **variable parameters** which are *unknown at run-time*.

**Edit:** Just to emphasize, the invocation **assumes** that the string parameter in the form of a C string format is less than the maximum size represented by `PANIC_BUF_LEN` in the above **example**, nit-picky aside, that is to illustrate how a function can take in a number of standard C formatting strings used, for example, one can specify `%d` in the string format, and expect a `int` to match up the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It's not overloading in the C++ sense, but it can be used for a similar effect.  The `...` indicates that the function takes any number of additional arguments after the named arguments (there has to be at least one named argument), and *the additional arguments can have any type* (sort of).<sup>1</sup>  The implementation of such a function has to be able to deduce the number and type of its additional arguments at runtime.  For instance, `printf` can print any built-in type, and any number of things at a time, but you have to give it `%` codes in the format string that correspond to the actual arguments.

One notable example of variable arguments used to simulate C++-style overloading is the [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) system call, which in C++ terms has two overloads:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

and the manpage is written that way, but if you look in `<fcntl.h>` you will discover that the actual declaration is

```
int open(const char *, int, ...);
```

The implementation only looks at the third argument if the `O_CREAT` bit is set in the flags, and it's documented that you *must* provide the third argument if you set that bit.  As usual in C, if you do it wrong, the compiler cheerfully watches it blow up on you at runtime.

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to a vestigial language feature called "[default argument promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls)", some numeric types get turned into other, larger numeric types when passed as additional arguments to a function that takes a variable number of arguments.  You only have to worry about this if you are writing the body of such a function.

Answer (score 0):

No. The "..." signifies variable arguments.

Overloading is when compiler mingles the name to produce multiple functions with different argument set. In C, the function name is not getting mingled, but the function can accept 1 or more arguments.