# Function arguments like printf in C

Tags: c, printf

I want to implement a function `Myprintf()` that takes arguments like `printf()`.
Now I am doing this by:

```
sprintf(demoString, "Num=%d String=%s", num, str);
Myprintf(demoString);
```

I want to replace this function call as:

```
Myprintf("Num=%d String=%s", num, str);
```

How is this possible?

Comment: I guess this link is right for you: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

extern int Myprintf(const char *fmt, ...);

int Myprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buffer[4096];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int rc = vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    ...print the formatted buffer...
    return rc;
}
```

It isn't clear from your question exactly how the output is done; your existing `Myprintf()` presumably outputs it somewhere, maybe with `fprintf()`.  If that's the case, you might write instead:

```
int Myprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int rc = vfprintf(debug_fp, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return rc;
}
```

If you don't want to use the return value, declare the function as `void` and don't bother with the variable `rc`.

This is a fairly common pattern for '`printf()` cover functions'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a [function with variable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around), and use [vsprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/) to build the string.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` and its relatives are in a family of functions called *variadic functions* and there are macros/functions in the [`<stddef.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16) header in the C standard library to manipulate variadic argument lists. Look at the GNU docs for examples: [How Variadic Functions are Defined and Used](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/How-Variadic.html#How-Variadic).