# Create a prototype function with additional arguments in C

Tags: c, arguments, prototype

As we know `printf()` function, it can hold characters and if needed could have additional arguments. Ex. `printf("Programmer");` `printf("Programmer %d",14);`

**How could I add additional arguments in a prototype function?** 
Is it something like `some_func(char *str, ...)` ?

Comment: "Is it something like some_func(char *str, ...)?" - Yes.

Comment: part of the standard; you can get some example from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around) or even from [wp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use variable number of arguments in C you need to include the following library

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

`printf()` in C is an example of function that takes variable number of arguments.

```
int printf(const char *fmt, ...)
```

More info [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the variable argument list provided in C.

Here is a short tutorial on this functionality:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html