# Variable number argument list starts on its second entry

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2012, when I run the following code, which just calculates the average of numbers, gives an erroneous answer. The `for` loop - for some reason - starts on `Number = 1` and goes one entry beyond `Number = 9`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

float avg(int Count, ...)
{
    va_list Numbers;
    va_start(Numbers, Count);
    int Sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Count;  ++i)
    {
        int entry = va_arg(Numbers, int);
        printf("%d   %d\n", i, entry);
        Sum += entry;   
    }
    va_end(Numbers);

    float av = Sum/Count;
    return(av);
}

int main()
{
    float Average = avg(10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    printf("The average of the first 10 whole numbers: %f\n", Average);
}
```

I checked e.g. [Passing variable number of arguments around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around) but I can't figure out why `va_arg` pulls the second entry from `Numbers` first. The result of this code on my machine is:

```
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
9   790803
The average of the first 10 whole numbers: 79084.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `va_arg()`, it only processes the variable parts of the argument list, not the initial part with named parameters. So the first call to `va_arg` gets `entry = 1` because that's the first argument in the variable part.

The `Number` argument should be the count of additional arguments, it shouldn't count itself. Since you're only passing 9 variable arguments, you should call it as

```
float Average = avg(9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

Also, when you calculate the average, one of the division operands needs to be `float`. Otherwise, it will calculate an integer quotient, which rounds the result, and then assign that rounded result to the `av` variable. A simple solution is to declare `Sum` to be `float` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have set `Count` to 10. If you tell `avg` that there are 10 numbers, but you only supply 9, you are invoking undefined behavior.